# programmatically expand a tree inside a dojox.TreeGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a simple tree grid and i need to programmatically expand a row to show its children. In essence i need to fake the click event that triggers the opening of the tree. 
see and example here http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_treegrid_model_lazy.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used the TreeGrid, but from the [API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid.expandoFetch) docs, it looks like you want to use the `expandoFetch(rowIndex,open)` function with the `open` parameter as `true`:

`myTreeGrid.expandoFetch(0,true);`